# wordpress - pull same blog data into multiple sites

Tags: html, css, wordpress, mobile

I have a wordpress blog currently installed at blog.mydomain.com. I am creating a mobile version of my site at m.mydomain.com which will have a blog section. Obviously I want to use the same database and just pull in all the blog posts and display them with CSS customized for the mobile site. How can I accomplish this?

EDIT: Here is the code I'm trying to insert the blog posts into:

```
<div class="blog">
    <div class="section-header">
        <img class="section-logo" src="images/logo-small.png" alt="img">
        <a href="#" class="section-navigation-deploy"><img class="navigation-deploy-icon" src="images/nav-icon.png" alt="img"></a>
        <div class="clear"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="deco-open"></div>

   <?php
require('http://blog.mydomain.com/wp-blog-header.php');
$posts = get_posts('numberposts=-1&order=DSC&orderby=date');
?>

   <?php foreach ($posts as $post) : start_wp(); ?>
<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<section><?php the_excerpt(); ?></section>
<?php endforeach; ?>


    <div class="deco-close"></div>


</div>
```

Comment: why don't you just install a plugin that serves a mobile optimized theme for mobile browsers?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider because the mobile blog is on a different domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
  require('./blog/wp-blog-header.php');
  $posts = get_posts('numberposts=-1&order=DSC&orderby=date');
?>
```

The require should point to the `wp-blog-header.php` file in the root of your blog directory.

*This is the code I am currently using in `wwwroot/index.php` and my blog is in `wwwroot/blog` Once I get `$posts` I'll display the contents with:*

```
<?php foreach ($posts as $post) : start_wp(); ?>
  <article>
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <section><?php the_excerpt(); ?></section>
  </article>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, trying to implement now. Is this legal? require('http://blog.mydomain.com/wp-blog-header.php');

Comment: Also, where do I place this code within my index file? I have changed it from .html to .php, but when I insert your code the page stops rendering at the point I paste the code.

Comment: I put it halfway down my index.php, right before the `foreach` that iterates through the posts. Also, I was not able to get `require('blog.mydomain.com/wp-blog-header.php';);` to work, I just used the relative URL.

Comment: I updated my original post to show where I'm trying to put it.

Comment: Is it possible to use a relative URL on different domains? My blog is at blog.mydomain.com, and my mobile site is at m.mydomain.com

Comment: Actually I got it to work doing this: require('../../blog/wp-blog-header.php');